# How to preserve selected value of a select controller in a Razor Component?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, razor-components

There is the following Razor Component:

```
@using System.Collections
<h3>User</h3>

<div>
    <label>Role:</label>
    <select @bind="SelectedRoleId">
        @foreach (var role in Roles)
        {
            <option value="@role.Id">@role.Name</option>
        }
    </select>
</div>

<div>
    <label>Permission:</label>
    <select @bind="selectedPermissionId">
        @foreach (var permission in Permissions)
        {
            <option value="@permission.Id">@permission.Name</option>
        }
    </select>
</div>

@code {
    private int selectedPermissionId;
    private int _selectedRoleId;
    private List<Role> Roles { get; set; }
    private List<Permission> Permissions { get; set; }

    private int SelectedRoleId
    {
        get => _selectedRoleId;
        set
        {
            _selectedRoleId = value;
            switch (_selectedRoleId)
            {
                case 1:
                    Permissions = new List<Permission>
                    {
                        new () { Id = 1, Name = "Write" },
                        new () { Id = 2, Name = "Read" }
                    };
                    selectedPermissionId = 1;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Permissions = new List<Permission>
                    {
                        new() { Id = 2, Name = "Read" }
                    };
                    selectedPermissionId = 2;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        Roles = new List<Role>
        {
            new() { Id = 1, Name = "Admin" },
            new() { Id = 2, Name = "User" }
        };
        SelectedRoleId = 1;
    }

    public class Role
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class Permission
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Output**

[image]

The problem is:

1. User selects Role=User => Permission=Read
2. User selects Role=Admin => Permission=Write

How can I preserve the selected value of Permission=Read after the second step, since the Admin role also has this Read permission?

Comment: Instead of having `private int selectedPermissionId`, what about just saving the `Permission` list to the property. Like this, `private Permission[] selectedPermissions`, and in your properties `set` statement you could associate permissions as so, `selectedPermissions = Permissions;`. And when you go to check permissions you iterate the `Permissions` list for the ID/Name for the action about to be performed. If a write is being performed then check for the 'Write' permission in the list, if read is performed then check for 'Read', etc. This will also support adding more permissions if needed.

Comment: Unfortunately, your point is not clear for me, eg. if I convert  `selectedPermissionId` to a list, then how can I detect the selected permission?

Comment: Once you would add any permission it would be in permission array. So it would check the ids in your array right?

Answer (score 0):

Here's your code with two main changes to make it work and a few other formatting changes:

1. I've added `@ref` to each option so that the Renderer can track each option properly as they are dynamically changed.
2. I've removing the setting of `//selectedPermissionId = 1;` which will always set it Admin whenever you change the role.
3. I've shown how you can do a `--  Select a Value --`  when the value is 0.

```cs
@page "/"

|<h3>User</h3>

<div class="mb-3">
    <label>Role:</label>
    <select class="form-select" @bind="SelectedRoleId">
        @if (SelectedRoleId == 0)
        {
            <option selected disabled value="0"> -- Select a Role -- </option>
        }
        @foreach (var role in Roles)
        {
            <option @key=role.Id value="@role.Id">@role.Name</option>
        }
    </select>
</div>

<div class="mb-3">
    <label>Permission:</label>
    <select class="form-select" @bind="selectedPermissionId">
        @if (selectedPermissionId == 0)
        {
            <option selected disabled value="0"> -- Select a Permission -- </option>
        }
        @foreach (var permission in Permissions)
        {
            <option @key=permission.Id value="@permission.Id">@permission.Name</option>
        }
    </select>
</div>

@code {
    private int selectedPermissionId;
    private int _selectedRoleId;
    private List<Role> Roles { get; set; } = new();
    private List<Permission> Permissions { get; set; } = new();

    private int SelectedRoleId
    {
        get => _selectedRoleId;
        set
        {
            _selectedRoleId = value;
            switch (_selectedRoleId)
            {
                case 1:
                    Permissions = new List<Permission>
                    {
                        new () { Id = 1, Name = "Write" },
                        new () { Id = 2, Name = "Read" }
                    };
                    //selectedPermissionId = 1;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Permissions = new List<Permission>
                    {
                        new() { Id = 2, Name = "Read" }
                    };
                    selectedPermissionId = 2;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        Roles = new List<Role>
        {
            new() { Id = 1, Name = "Admin" },
            new() { Id = 2, Name = "User" }
        };
        SelectedRoleId = 1;
    }

    public class Role
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    }

    public class Permission
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    }
}
```